# Reledmac / geometry: text going over bottom margin

Tags: margins, geometry, reledmac

I am struggling to have a text typeset within a specific frame. However, this is not the case. As you can see from the example I have attached, the text goes beyond the bottom margin. I'm not sure if this is an issue caused by the `geometry` or `reledmac` packages. Could you please help?

```
\documentclass[10pt, twoside]{memoir}
\usepackage{polyglossia,xunicode}
\usepackage[papersize={16cm, 22cm},textheight=17.5cm,top=2.5cm,headheight=4.22mm,headsep=2.78mm,bottom=2cm,footskip=0.5cm,left=2.35cm,right=2.75cm,nomarginpar,showframe,twoside]{geometry}
\usepackage{libertine}
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\usepackage[noresetlinenumannotation, series={A}, noend,noeledsec,noledgroup]{reledmac}
\newcommand{\bv}[1]{\linenumannotation{#1}}
\makeatletter
\Xwraplinenumannotation{\@firstofone}
\renewcommand{\linenumrep}[1]{}
\makeatother
\Xarrangement[A]{paragraph}
\begin{document}
\chapter*{}
\beginnumbering
  \linenummargin{inner}
\pstart
\noindent
\centering
    \ledouternote{A2\textit{r}}LOREM IPSUM
    \pend
    \pstart
    \noindent
\centering
DOLOR SIT AMET
    \pend
    \pstart
    \noindent
\centering
consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do
    \pend
    \pstart
    \noindent
\centering
elit, sed do incididunt
\pend[{\vspace{0pt}}]
  \pstart
\noindent
\centering
  Dolor Sit Amet
\pend[{\vspace{0pt}}]
  \endnumbering
  \firstlinenum{1}
  \linenumincrement{1}
  \beginnumbering
  \linenummargin{inner}
  \pstart
  \indent\justify\bv{1}Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut faucibus pulvinar elementum integer enim. Fermentum odio eu feugiat pretium nibh ipsum consequat nisl. Tempus urna et pharetra pharetra massa massa ultricies mi quis. Viverra aliquet eget sit amet tellus cras adipiscing enim eu. Elit duis tristique sollicitudin nibh sit amet. Proin fermentum leo vel orci porta. Pretium fusce id velit ut. Enim sed faucibus turpis in eu mi. In eu mi bibendum neque egestas congue quisque. Vel orci porta non pulvinar neque laoreet. Ut morbi tincidunt augue interdum. Ullamcorper dignissim cras tincidunt lobortis feugiat vivamus. Lacinia quis vel eros donec. Nisi quis eleifend quam adipiscing vitae proin sagittis nisl. Et odio pellentesque diam volutpat. Nunc sed id semper risus in hendrerit gravida rutrum quisque. Lacinia quis vel eros donec ac. Diam maecenas sed enim ut sem viverra aliquet eget\edtext{loremips}{\Afootnote{lorem ipsum}} aliquet diam.\bv{2} Nisi quis eleifend quam adipiscing vitae proin sagittis nisl. Et odio pellentesque diam volutpat. Nunc sed id semper risus in hendrerit gravida rutrum\edtext{lorem}{\Afootnote{loreeeem}} quisque. Lacinia quis vel eros donec ac. Diam maecenas sed enim ut sem viverra aliquet eget. \bv{3} Posuere lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur. Quisque non tellus orci ac auctor augue \edtext{ipsum}{\Afootnote{ipssum}} Scelerisque in dictum non consectetur a erat nam. Velit egestas dui id ornare arcu. \bv{4} Nunc pulvinar sapien et\edtext{dooolor}{\Afootnote{dodolor D}} ligula ullamcorper. Elementum eu facilisis sed odio morbi quis commodo odio. Facilisis gravida neque convallis a cras. Et \edtext{fammes}{\Afootnote{fammmesx D}} malesuada fames ac turpis. Faucibus interdum posuere lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipiscing. Sed blandit libero volutpat sed. Sem et tortor consequat id porta nibh venenatis\edtext{lorem}{\Afootnote{lorum D}} stas congue quisque. Vel orci porta non pulvinar neque laoreet. Ut morbi tincidunt augue interdum. Ullamcorper dignissim cras tinci. 
  \pend
  \endnumbering
  \end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Tex is not conceived to manage paragraphed footnote. Reledmac use an hack, which is very sensitive to geometry. As explained on § 19.1.6 of the handbook, you may have to redefine.

In you case, i get something correct with `footfudgefiddle`

```
\documentclass[10pt, twoside]{memoir}
\usepackage{polyglossia,xunicode}
\usepackage[papersize={16cm, 22cm},textheight=17.5cm,top=2.5cm,headheight=4.22mm,headsep=2.78mm,bottom=2cm,footskip=0.5cm,left=2.35cm,right=2.75cm,nomarginpar,showframe,twoside]{geometry}
\usepackage{libertine}
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\usepackage[noresetlinenumannotation, series={A}, noend,noeledsec,noledgroup]{reledmac}
\newcommand{\bv}[1]{\linenumannotation{#1}}
\makeatletter
\Xwraplinenumannotation{\@firstofone}
\renewcommand{\linenumrep}[1]{}
\makeatother
\renewcommand{\footfudgefiddle}{100}
\Xarrangement[A]{paragraph}
\begin{document}
\chapter*{}
\beginnumbering
  \linenummargin{inner}
\pstart
\noindent
\centering
    \ledouternote{A2\textit{r}}LOREM IPSUM
    \pend
    \pstart
    \noindent
\centering
DOLOR SIT AMET
    \pend
    \pstart
    \noindent
\centering
consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do
    \pend
    \pstart
    \noindent
\centering
elit, sed do incididunt
\pend[{\vspace{0pt}}]
  \pstart
\noindent
\centering
  Dolor Sit Amet
\pend[{\vspace{0pt}}]
  \endnumbering
  \firstlinenum{1}
  \linenumincrement{1}
  \beginnumbering
  \linenummargin{inner}
  \pstart
  \indent\justify\bv{1}Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut faucibus pulvinar elementum integer enim. Fermentum odio eu feugiat pretium nibh ipsum consequat nisl. Tempus urna et pharetra pharetra massa massa ultricies mi quis. Viverra aliquet eget sit amet tellus cras adipiscing enim eu. Elit duis tristique sollicitudin nibh sit amet. Proin fermentum leo vel orci porta. Pretium fusce id velit ut. Enim sed faucibus turpis in eu mi. In eu mi bibendum neque egestas congue quisque. Vel orci porta non pulvinar neque laoreet. Ut morbi tincidunt augue interdum. Ullamcorper dignissim cras tincidunt lobortis feugiat vivamus. Lacinia quis vel eros donec. Nisi quis eleifend quam adipiscing vitae proin sagittis nisl. Et odio pellentesque diam volutpat. Nunc sed id semper risus in hendrerit gravida rutrum quisque. Lacinia quis vel eros donec ac. Diam maecenas sed enim ut sem viverra aliquet eget\edtext{loremips}{\Afootnote{lorem ipsum}} aliquet diam.\bv{2} Nisi quis eleifend quam adipiscing vitae proin sagittis nisl. Et odio pellentesque diam volutpat. Nunc sed id semper risus in hendrerit gravida rutrum\edtext{lorem}{\Afootnote{loreeeem}} quisque. Lacinia quis vel eros donec ac. Diam maecenas sed enim ut sem viverra aliquet eget. \bv{3} Posuere lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur. Quisque non tellus orci ac auctor augue \edtext{ipsum}{\Afootnote{ipssum}} Scelerisque in dictum non consectetur a erat nam. Velit egestas dui id ornare arcu. \bv{4} Nunc pulvinar sapien et\edtext{dooolor}{\Afootnote{dodolor D}} ligula ullamcorper. Elementum eu facilisis sed odio morbi quis commodo odio. Facilisis gravida neque convallis a cras. Et \edtext{fammes}{\Afootnote{fammmesx D}} malesuada fames ac turpis. Faucibus interdum posuere lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipiscing. Sed blandit libero volutpat sed. Sem et tortor consequat id porta nibh venenatis\edtext{lorem}{\Afootnote{lorum D}} stas congue quisque. Vel orci porta non pulvinar neque laoreet. Ut morbi tincidunt augue interdum. Ullamcorper dignissim cras tinci.
  \pend
  \endnumbering
  \end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you @Maïeul. That took care of the bottom margins, but now the text goes over the right margin... [link](https://www.dropbox.com/s/scx6tabmm2a9i5x/Screenshot%202019-07-17%2010.07.48.png?dl=0}

Comment: Try some value between between 64 and 100. But as i said, paragraphed footnote are quite complex.

Comment: Thank you @Maïeul. I tried every number you suggested and nothing worked. The manual suggests to use `\Xmaxhnotes`, but even that doesn't take solve the problem of the right margin break. Is there another way of defining the page, header and footer margins without using the `geometry` package and in a way that wouldn't clash with `reledmac`?

Comment: sorry, I don't knwo. I think really the problem is with paragraphed footnote, but it is a very hard code.

Comment: Not sure if I understood correctly your last comment, @Maïeul. Are you saying there is no solution to the problem of notes going over the margins? Sorry but I got stuck at this specific issue.

Comment: I say mostly that I don't know if there is actually any solution, and if if it could have.