# Page numbers in footer and in header (should be in footer only)

Tags: margins, page-numbering

The publisher who accepted my book demands an e-book format with 25mm for left, top, right and bottom margins. As soon as I changed the margins the page numbers have gone missing. In the MWE I provide the problem is different (I wonder whether the cause is the same): page numbers jump from the footer to the header. I wanted them to be in the footer only.

````
\documentclass[12pt,oneside]{book}
\usepackage[a4paper,includefoot,lmargin=25mm,rmargin=25mm,tmargin=25mm]{geometry}
\setlength{\parskip}{8pt}
\usepackage[series={A}]{reledmac}
\Xarrangement[A]{paragraph}
\arrangementX[A]{paragraph}
\lineation{page}
\usepackage[polutonikogreek,latin,portuges]{babel}
\usepackage{indentfirst}
\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Source Sans Pro}
\usepackage{blindtext}

\begin{document}

\part{Introdução}
    \blindtext
\Blindtext
\blindtext
\Blindtext
\part{Texto original}

\beginnumbering

\pstart
\edtext{Quod}{\Afootnote{quot \textit{iterauit H}}} \edtext{si}{\Afootnote{et \textit{H}}} dixerimus, non cogitando nos sed legendo, neque ex proprio cerebro, sed ex divinis oraculis tempora et \edtext{rationes}{\Afootnote{rationis \textit{U}}} temporum diligenti supputatione \edtext{deprompturos}{\Afootnote{deprompturos \textit{H} demonstraturos \textit{U}}}; ex ipsis certe monumentis sacris, experientia duce, multipliciter redarguemur. Et primo quidem ex Chronologia praeteritorum temporum ab exordio mundi non aliunde, nisi a Sacris \edtext{Tabulis}{\Afootnote{Tabulis \textit{LZN} tabulis \textit{TGHBAJ}}} desumpta. Lege, si vacat, ex Hebraeis, Josephum et Philonem, ex Graecis Patribus Theophilum Antiochenum, Clementem Alexandrinum, Originem, Eusebium Caesariensem, Epiphanium, Anastasium Sinaitam, Hesychium, et utrumque Nicephorum 
\pend


\endnumbering

\end{document}```
````

Answer (score 1):

Add to your preamble

```
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\fancyhf{}
\fancyfoot[R]{\thepage} % page number on bottom right
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}% supress horizontal line
\pagestyle{fancy} % activate the style fancy
```

[image: a]

to make the page number appear in the bottom right of the page. Upper right is the default behavior. It is not dependent of the margins.

Comment: It works in the MWE I provided. When I tried in the file with the manuscript of my book the numbers are still missing (they appear in the indices though)... I have put the same preamble I have for my book in the MWE above and it still works. Any clues where should I search for the cause of missing page numbers?

Comment: @Sintram Replace the content of your working document with same lipsum. Perhaps is something inside.

Comment: I replaced (safe for a transcription of a 16th cent. work). It prints the page number in the center (as it should) in every 1st page of a \part . Then the page number goes to the header, aligned to the right. There is a caveat about using geometry with reledmac here: [link](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/500265/reledmac-geometry-text-going-over-bottom-margin)

Comment: @Sintram If to the answer of the link you add `fancyhdr` etc., and more content to go over several pages, the page number will appear in the bottom right.

Comment: No, indeed it keeps behaving  like I said before: page numbers only in the beginning of \part or \chapter. If there is a way to define margins without geometry package may be that will provide a solution.

Comment: I think you were right: the problem was I suppose in the specifications for the title page which was not enclosed within \begin{titlepage}. At least when I closed that piece of code things changed.